# How can I know if my phone has SIM card on Windows Phone device?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Two questions as below:

1. How can I know if my phone has SIM card on Windows Phone device?
2. If my windows phone device has an invalid SIM card, how can I know that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this topic on MSDN:

[Network and Network Interface Information for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202867%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Especially this: [How to: Get Network Information for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202859%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
and this: [How to: Determine the Mobile Operator for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202875%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

UPDATE:

From my test through the code provided by the MSDN examples above, I've got the results for your reference:

I put the app onto a device without SIM card, WiFi connected, and get:

`DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator` "empty, yes, it's emtpy"
`DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable.ToString()` True
`DeviceNetowrkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled.ToString()` False
`DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataRoamingEnabled.ToString()` False
`DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled.ToString()` True

Therefore, if there's a SIM card inside, the CellularMobileOperator got be something but not empty, you can utilize this to determine if the device has a SIM card inside.

But I haven't take consider of what if an "invalid SIM" inside the phone will happens.

Comment: That is for Windows Phone 8 or 8.1 Silverlight.. isn't there anything for WinRT?